# How to make an API call using Meteor and React

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, meteor, methods

I have this Meteor method:

```
Meteor.methods({

'RESTcall':function () {
        this.unblock();
        return Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://www.viaggiatreno.it/viaggiatrenonew/resteasy/viaggiatreno/soluzioniViaggioNew/228/458/2017-05-31T00:00:00");}});
```

And a React Component.jsx with a button in the render function that call a function like this:

```
   search(){
      Meteor.call("RESTcall", (error, response)=>{
                 console.log(response); //this works
                 this.setState({results: response}); //this throws an exception
            }
      });
}
```

The question is what can I do to use response out of the callback function  in order to render its content.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your code you `console.log(results)` but there is no `results` defined anywhere. What is the output of `console.log(response)`? and what kind of exception is thrown?

Comment: Sorry yes console.log (response) works and it's a JSON response

Comment: Can you provide the exception? Your call seems good. This.setState should work because you are using an arrow function. I guess the problem is from the http call, maybe a CORS problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make a small change which is given below. I have not tested it but I think it should work.

```
 search(){
      var that = this; /*Since the setState method in this is accessible here*/
      Meteor.call("RESTcall", (error, response)=>{
                 console.log(response); 
                 that.setState({results: response});
            }
      });
```

Comment: He is using an arrow function so this should be bind the the react class and this.setState should work.